# IMG tag writing the data source

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image

I have variable loading images.

I would like to be able to programatically appended the images with the data from an angular directive.

currently the images load as `<img src="api/imagespecs/&return=data"/>`

however I would like to grab the returned data and put that into the image tag from the use of an angular directive.

Using the angular directive, I get back the responded binary image data that is used in the image above.

I am appending the image to the view which works in other areas with images however the image will not load.

I have attempted to insert the data directly into the src which just writes the string.

I have attempted to convert the responded data to base64 and display it that way within a search and that does not work either for me.

I have a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FUDVvpki) of the image data that I receive from the endpoint without any change to it.

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc for ng-src documentation.

Comment: it is not clear in which format your `image data` is from your given `pastebin`. If it is base64 encoded format you can directly use it in `<img src="{raw image data}" ... `

Comment: @HimelNagRana Hi Himel, the format is base image binary data returned from my endpoint

Comment: Hi @JamesBassDavies, In that case you need to convert that data to base64 data and then show. AFAIK there is no other way to show binary data in web page.